# Wordpress theme make the full width home page content row

Tags: wordpress

im using a wordpress theme from [mywiki knowledge base](https://wordpress.org/themes/mywiki/)
i want to make its home page template in full width with no sidebar and the category row to be 3 by 3, i mean it should be 3 categories each row

i have check the support forum and found someone already raised the [same question 14months ago](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/make-mywiki-page-template-have-no-sidebar-and-go-full-width/) but still no answer to that,

some how i manage to remove the sidebar and make the home page in full width 
but now the problem is category row is showing 2 categories only and i want it to show 3 categories in row

i've edited the [Template-wiki.php](https://themes.svn.wordpress.org/mywiki/2.5/template-wiki.php) and comment out the sidebar `//get_sidebar(); // sidebar 1 ?>` 
now my page look like this [mywiki-page_without_sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4e6G1.jpg) with large empty portion on the right

i hope someone will figure out the solution to make the 3 categories in a row

Theme files can be accessed from [here](https://themes.svn.wordpress.org/mywiki/2.5/)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This one should be relatively easy to solve. Assuming you are working with your mentionted template (template-wiki.php), you will find a line of code within that template like the following:

`<div id="main" class="col-sm-8 clearfix nopadding-left" role="main">`

What you want to do, is change this line to the following:

```
<div id="main" class="col-sm-12 clearfix nopadding-left" role="main">
```

Looks like the theme is using bootstrap, by having col-sm-12 in there rather than col-sm-8, your content should be 100% width of the parent container.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, 
I did change the line but still no luck, i guess it need some php modification ?
this [Sample Page](http://hdr4k.tk/wp/) i created incase someone want to use firebug 

BTW i learn something new about bootstrap **col-sm-12** :) thank you

Comment: In theory, it really shouldn't require PHP modification, instead it would require some additional HTML and CSS. Though, it's a bit odd as to why the grid isn't going 100%. There may be another parent wrapping the column and that's what isn't allowing the child element to go 100%. Do you have a live test link for further debugging purposes?

Comment: how about this [online demo test with admin access](https://s1.demo.opensourcecms.com/wordpress/wp-login.php) ?
 

Username: **opensourcecms**
Password: **opensourcecms**

You can download the theme MYWIKI and select the static front page and use the WIKI template in Page menu